# Performance of SPI vs PLPGSQL

Tags: postgresql

What percentage of performance gain could I achieve if I rewrite all my PLPGSQL functions (for Postgres 9.6) in C language using Server Programming Interface (SPI)?

I am not including the time of delivering the data from Server to Client (the network time), I am just talking about getting the data at server side and formatting it before sending the packets out to the network. I know it all depends on the application, but if we take as example a backend for webmail or a website like StackOverflow, how much gain would I get in performance? Is it worth it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PL/pgSQL is not very performant, so you will certainly be faster with a C function than with a PL/pgSQL function. The more processing is done in PL/pgSQL itself, the more noticable the performance gain would be. If most of the PL/pgSQL time is spent in SQL queries, you won't see a big performance gain.

So it depends on the individual use case if it is worth the effort or not.
It is certainly more difficult to write a C function than a PL/pgSQL function.